# OOP for chess game?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I came across such a OOP design on web(a brief version):

```
public abstract class ChessPieceBase {
    abstract boolean canBeChecked();
    abstract boolean isSupportCastle();
}

public class King extends ChessPieceBase { ... }
public class Queen extends ChessPieceBase { ... }

public class Position { // represents chess positions in compact form
    ArrayList<ChessPieceBase> black;
    ArrayList<ChessPieceBase> white;
}

public class ChessPieceTurn { };

public abstract class PlayerBase {
    public abstract ChessPieceTurn getTurn(Position p);
}

class ComputerPlayer extends PlayerBase {
    public ChessPieceTurn getTurn(Position p) { return null; }
}

public class HumanPlayer extends PlayerBase {
    public ChessPieceTurn getTurn(Position p) { return null; }
}

public class GameManager {
    void processTurn(PlayerBase player) { };
    boolean acceptTurn(ChessPieceTurn turn) { return true; };
    Position currentPosition;
}
```

I have some difficulty understanding the design, not knowing if i did not understand OOP or understanding chess :(. From top to bottom:

1. ChessPieceBase is the abstract base class for all pieces,  king, queen, rook, bishop, knight, and pawn, right? so i see King and Queen extend ChessPieceBase.
2. Position, according to comments, should record a global current positions of pieces for black and white. It is implemented as an arraylist of ChessPieceBase, but ChessPieceBase does not contain any position info member, so where is position info stored?
3. what's ChessPieceTurn? if it's a 'my turn, your turn' concept, why getTurn() func in player class need 'Position p' parameter and return null?
4. GameManager class. 'currentPosition' record a global state of the game, 'acceptTurn()' does not seem to do anything, 'processTurn()' get turn from player and handle like referee. Hope i understand this last one correct.

And if possible, can someone write a little main() function to show how it works? At this time i am just confused.

Any idea from you on how you see what classes should look like for chess game are welcome,

Thanks,

Comment: May be the question is too obvious for many of you?